# Expected sum of picked numbers from set

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, expectation

Let suppose that I have a finite set $X$ of natural numbers. 
I keep drawing, with reintroduction and uniform probability, from this set until the sum of the extracted numbers, $S$, is bigger or equal than the constant value $\bar S$. What is the expected value $E[S]$ of this sum?

I would solve it in this following way.

Let $e_n$ be the expected value of the sum if the starting value is $n$, therefore $E[S]=e_0$. It should hold this recurrence relation

$e_n=\frac{1}{|X|}\sum_{i\in X}e_{n+i}$

where $|X|$ is the cardinality of my set. Is it true? I am not able to justify rigorously why this relation holds. Obviously if this hold, the solution can be implemented numerically in a very trivial way.

Are there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that your recurrence relation is true (remark that $e_n=n$, provided $n\ge\bar S$). This is a homogeneous linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients, which can be solved by [standard methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving).